# How can I undo an Automatic Weight?

Tags: bones, weight-painting

I can't seem to find a place to undo an automatic weight I applied to my mesh. Is it possible to undo this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Just go into the Vertex group. Look for the down arrow button, right click on it and select "delete all groups".

[image]

Comment: Just found it, i delete all the vertex groups, but the problem persist =(

Comment: im sorry , i answer here the last question,thank you for telling me.

Comment: If you have already applied scale to your mesh and did automatic weight, and the weight still isnt right, I am afraid you have to add and remove those vertex group manually after you apply auto weight. And also to weight paint manually.